# What's the difference between --read-only and just permit SELECT queries?

Tags: mysql, select, amazon-rds, read-only-database

I'm using **Amazon Aurora** and I have two endpoints, my endpoint which can read/write are having some issues to execute queries, these are the issues:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1290 The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement, query was: UPDATE `integration` SET `setup_type` = ? WHERE (integration_id='4')
```

---

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1290 The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement, query was: UPDATE `indexer_state` SET `indexer_id` = ?, `status` = ?, `updated` = '2018-03-12 14:38:45', `hash_config` = ? WHERE (state_id='1')
```

Amazon uses the **global --read-only** configuration in one of the servers.
What's the difference between to use **--read-only** and a user which can just execute **SELECT** queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user gets read only permission (`select`), it will not be able to write/update/etc even when the global `read-only` value is 0.
However, [a user with `\[SUPER\]` privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super), will be able to write on a server where global `read-only` value is set to 1.

One more difference is that read only permissions are very granular, while `read-only` variable is a server wide variable.

Usually, you'd give `SELECT` permissions to users who you want them to read from a Server/DB/Table where other users can write. On the other hand, you set `read-only` variable to 1 when you want all but super users to be able to write to. For example, a read slave.

Answer (score 2):

To the user, probably no difference.

To the *system* integrity, `--read-only` prevents you from accidentally writing to a Slave, thereby messing up the Replication integrity.

Aurora has no control (I assume) over whether you grant write permission and happen to let them hit a Slave with an `UPDATE`.  This is an easy, simple, prevention.